# JSF - SelectOneMenu no captura el id

Tags: java, jsf, java-ee, jpa

estoy trabajando con JSF y estoy utilizando un selectOneMenu, el problema es que cuando trato de capturar el id del objeto en el selectOneMenu Me lo envia nulo.

el código del selectOneMenu es el siguiente:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="oajProceso" value="#{oajComiteProcesoController.selected.oajProceso}" title="#{bundle.EditOajComiteProcesoTitle_oajProceso}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{bundle.EditOajComiteProcesoRequiredMessage_oajProceso}">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{oajComiteProcesoController.listadoComiteProcesosJudiciales()}" var="com" itemLabel="#{com.oajProceso.numeroProceso}" itemValue="#{com.oajProceso.idProceso}"/>
                    <f:ajax execute="#{oajComiteProcesoController.createInformacionComite(com.oajProceso.idProceso)}" immediate="true"/>
                </h:selectOneMenu>
```

el codigo con el que lo lleno es:

```
public List<OajComiteProceso> listadoComiteProcesosJudiciales(){

    List <OajComiteProceso> lista = ejbFacade.listadoComitesProceso();

    return lista;
}
```

el select carga normal pero al pasar el valor envia null.

agradezco me puedan decir que estoy haciendo mal.

Codigo Clase OajComiteProceso.

```
public class OajComiteProceso implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@EmbeddedId
protected OajComiteProcesoPK oajComiteProcesoPK;
@Size(max = 2000)
@Column(name = "DECISION_COMITE_PROCESO")
private String decisionComiteProceso;
@Column(name = "FECHA_REGISTRO_DECISION")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date fechaRegistroDecision;
// @Max(value=?)  @Min(value=?)//if you know range of your decimal fields consider using these annotations to enforce field validation
@Column(name = "CUANTIA_APROBADA_COMITE_PROC")
private BigDecimal cuantiaAprobadaComiteProc;
@Size(max = 1000)
@Column(name = "OTROS_COMITE_PROCESO")
private String otrosComiteProceso;
@JoinColumn(name = "OAJ_COMITE_ID_COMITE", referencedColumnName = "ID_COMITE", insertable = false, updatable = false)
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private OajComite oajComite;
@JoinColumn(name = "OAJ_PROCESO_ID_PROCESO", referencedColumnName = "ID_PROCESO", insertable = false, updatable = false)
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private OajProceso oajProceso;
@Column(name = "FECHA_INFORMACION_COMITE")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date fechaInformacionComite;
@Size(min = 2, max = 100)
@Column(name = "DECISION_INFORMACION_COMITE")
private String decisionInformacionComite;
@Size(max = 500)
@Column(name = "OTROS_INFORMACION_COMITE")
private String otrosInformacionComite;
@Column(name = "FECHA_REGISTRO_INFORMACION_COMITE")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date fechaRegistroInformacionComite;
@Column(name = "ESTADO_INFORMACION_PROCESO")
private long estadoInformacionComite;

public OajComiteProceso() {
}

public OajComiteProceso(OajComiteProcesoPK oajComiteProcesoPK) {
    this.oajComiteProcesoPK = oajComiteProcesoPK;
}

public OajComiteProceso(long oajComiteIdComite, long oajProcesoIdProceso) {
    this.oajComiteProcesoPK = new OajComiteProcesoPK(oajComiteIdComite, oajProcesoIdProceso);
}

public OajComiteProcesoPK getOajComiteProcesoPK() {
    return oajComiteProcesoPK;
}

public void setOajComiteProcesoPK(OajComiteProcesoPK oajComiteProcesoPK) {
    this.oajComiteProcesoPK = oajComiteProcesoPK;
}

public String getDecisionComiteProceso() {
    return decisionComiteProceso;
}

public void setDecisionComiteProceso(String decisionComiteProceso) {
    this.decisionComiteProceso = decisionComiteProceso;
}

public Date getFechaRegistroDecision() {
    return fechaRegistroDecision;
}

public void setFechaRegistroDecision(Date fechaRegistroDecision) {
    this.fechaRegistroDecision = fechaRegistroDecision;
}

public BigDecimal getCuantiaAprobadaComiteProc() {
    return cuantiaAprobadaComiteProc;
}

public void setCuantiaAprobadaComiteProc(BigDecimal cuantiaAprobadaComiteProc) {
    this.cuantiaAprobadaComiteProc = cuantiaAprobadaComiteProc;
}

public String getOtrosComiteProceso() {
    return otrosComiteProceso;
}

public void setOtrosComiteProceso(String otrosComiteProceso) {
    this.otrosComiteProceso = otrosComiteProceso;
}

public OajComite getOajComite() {
    return oajComite;
}

public void setOajComite(OajComite oajComite) {
    this.oajComite = oajComite;
}

public OajProceso getOajProceso() {
    return oajProceso;
}

public void setOajProceso(OajProceso oajProceso) {
    this.oajProceso = oajProceso;
}

public Date getFechaInformacionComite() {
    return fechaInformacionComite;
}

public void setFechaInformacionComite(Date fechaInformacionComite) {
    this.fechaInformacionComite = fechaInformacionComite;
}

public String getDecisionInformacionComite() {
    return decisionInformacionComite;
}

public void setDecisionInformacionComite(String decisionInformacionComite) {
    this.decisionInformacionComite = decisionInformacionComite;
}

public String getOtrosInformacionComite() {
    return otrosInformacionComite;
}

public void setOtrosInformacionComite(String otrosInformacionComite) {
    this.otrosInformacionComite = otrosInformacionComite;
}

public Date getFechaRegistroInformacionComite() {
    return fechaRegistroInformacionComite;
}

public void setFechaRegistroInformacionComite(Date fechaRegistroInformacionComite) {
    this.fechaRegistroInformacionComite = fechaRegistroInformacionComite;
}

public long getEstadoInformacionComite() {
    return estadoInformacionComite;
}

public void setEstadoInformacionComite(long estadoInformacionComite) {
    this.estadoInformacionComite = estadoInformacionComite;
}



@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 0;
    hash += (oajComiteProcesoPK != null ? oajComiteProcesoPK.hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
    if (!(object instanceof OajComiteProceso)) {
        return false;
    }
    OajComiteProceso other = (OajComiteProceso) object;
    if ((this.oajComiteProcesoPK == null && other.oajComiteProcesoPK != null) || (this.oajComiteProcesoPK != null && !this.oajComiteProcesoPK.equals(other.oajComiteProcesoPK))) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "com.mt.model.entity.OajComiteProceso[ oajComiteProcesoPK=" + oajComiteProcesoPK + " ]";
}
```

}

la clase controller es:

public class OajComiteProcesoController implements Serializable {

```
private OajComiteProceso current;
private DataModel items = null;
@EJB
private com.mt.dao.facade.OajComiteProcesoFacade ejbFacade;
private PaginationHelper pagination;
private int selectedItemIndex;

public OajComiteProcesoController() {
}

public OajComiteProceso getSelected() {
    if (current == null) {
        current = new OajComiteProceso();
        current.setOajComiteProcesoPK(new com.mt.model.entity.OajComiteProcesoPK());
        selectedItemIndex = -1;
    }
    return current;
}

private OajComiteProcesoFacade getFacade() {
    return ejbFacade;
}

public PaginationHelper getPagination() {
    if (pagination == null) {
        pagination = new PaginationHelper(10) {

            @Override
            public int getItemsCount() {
                return getFacade().count();
            }

            @Override
            public DataModel createPageDataModel() {
                return new ListDataModel(getFacade().findRange(new int[]{getPageFirstItem(), getPageFirstItem() + getPageSize()}));
            }
        };
    }
    return pagination;
}

public String prepareList() {
    recreateModel();
    return "List";
}

public String prepareView() {
    current = (OajComiteProceso) getItems().getRowData();
    selectedItemIndex = pagination.getPageFirstItem() + getItems().getRowIndex();
    return "View";
}

public String prepareCreate() {
    current = new OajComiteProceso();
    current.setOajComiteProcesoPK(new com.mt.model.entity.OajComiteProcesoPK());
    selectedItemIndex = -1;
    return "Create";
}

public String create() {
    try {
        current.getOajComiteProcesoPK().setOajProcesoIdProceso(current.getOajProceso().getIdProceso());
        current.getOajComiteProcesoPK().setOajComiteIdComite(current.getOajComite().getIdComite());
        getFacade().create(current);
        JsfUtil.addSuccessMessage(ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("OajComiteProcesoCreated"));
        return prepareCreate();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(e, ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("PersistenceErrorOccured"));
        return null;
    }
}

public String prepareEdit() {
    current = (OajComiteProceso) getItems().getRowData();
    selectedItemIndex = pagination.getPageFirstItem() + getItems().getRowIndex();
    return "Edit";
}

public String update() {
    try {
        current.getOajComiteProcesoPK().setOajProcesoIdProceso(current.getOajProceso().getIdProceso());
        current.getOajComiteProcesoPK().setOajComiteIdComite(current.getOajComite().getIdComite());
        getFacade().edit(current);
        JsfUtil.addSuccessMessage(ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("OajComiteProcesoUpdated"));
        return "View";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(e, ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("PersistenceErrorOccured"));
        return null;
    }
}

public String destroy() {
    current = (OajComiteProceso) getItems().getRowData();
    selectedItemIndex = pagination.getPageFirstItem() + getItems().getRowIndex();
    performDestroy();
    recreatePagination();
    recreateModel();
    return "List";
}

public String destroyAndView() {
    performDestroy();
    recreateModel();
    updateCurrentItem();
    if (selectedItemIndex >= 0) {
        return "View";
    } else {
        // all items were removed - go back to list
        recreateModel();
        return "List";
    }
}

private void performDestroy() {
    try {
        getFacade().remove(current);
        JsfUtil.addSuccessMessage(ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("OajComiteProcesoDeleted"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(e, ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("PersistenceErrorOccured"));
    }
}

private void updateCurrentItem() {
    int count = getFacade().count();
    if (selectedItemIndex >= count) {
        // selected index cannot be bigger than number of items:
        selectedItemIndex = count - 1;
        // go to previous page if last page disappeared:
        if (pagination.getPageFirstItem() >= count) {
            pagination.previousPage();
        }
    }
    if (selectedItemIndex >= 0) {
        current = getFacade().findRange(new int[]{selectedItemIndex, selectedItemIndex + 1}).get(0);
    }
}

public DataModel getItems() {
    if (items == null) {
        items = getPagination().createPageDataModel();
    }
    return items;
}

private void recreateModel() {
    items = null;
}

private void recreatePagination() {
    pagination = null;
}

public String next() {
    getPagination().nextPage();
    recreateModel();
    return "List";
}

public String previous() {
    getPagination().previousPage();
    recreateModel();
    return "List";
}

public SelectItem[] getItemsAvailableSelectMany() {
    return JsfUtil.getSelectItems(ejbFacade.findAll(), false);
}

public SelectItem[] getItemsAvailableSelectOne() {
    return JsfUtil.getSelectItems(ejbFacade.findAll(), true);
}

public OajComiteProceso getOajComiteProceso(com.mt.model.entity.OajComiteProcesoPK id) {
    return ejbFacade.find(id);
}

@FacesConverter(forClass = OajComiteProceso.class)
public static class OajComiteProcesoControllerConverter implements Converter {

    private static final String SEPARATOR = "#";
    private static final String SEPARATOR_ESCAPED = "\\#";

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent component, String value) {
        if (value == null || value.length() == 0) {
            return null;
        }
        OajComiteProcesoController controller = (OajComiteProcesoController) facesContext.getApplication().getELResolver().
                getValue(facesContext.getELContext(), null, "oajComiteProcesoController");
        return controller.getOajComiteProceso(getKey(value));
    }

    com.mt.model.entity.OajComiteProcesoPK getKey(String value) {
        com.mt.model.entity.OajComiteProcesoPK key;
        String values[] = value.split(SEPARATOR_ESCAPED);
        key = new com.mt.model.entity.OajComiteProcesoPK();
        key.setOajComiteIdComite(Long.parseLong(values[0]));
        key.setOajProcesoIdProceso(Long.parseLong(values[1]));
        return key;
    }

    String getStringKey(com.mt.model.entity.OajComiteProcesoPK value) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(value.getOajComiteIdComite());
        sb.append(SEPARATOR);
        sb.append(value.getOajProcesoIdProceso());
        return sb.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent component, Object object) {
        if (object == null) {
            return null;
        }
        if (object instanceof OajComiteProceso) {
            OajComiteProceso o = (OajComiteProceso) object;
            return getStringKey(o.getOajComiteProcesoPK());
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("object " + object + " is of type " + object.getClass().getName() + "; expected type: " + OajComiteProceso.class.getName());
        }
    }

}

/****************************************************************************/



public List<OajComiteProceso> listadoComiteProcesosJudiciales(){
    Long estado = 2L;
    List <OajComiteProceso> lista = ejbFacade.listadoComitesProceso(estado);

    for (OajComiteProceso comites : lista) {
        System.out.println("los comites son: " + comites);
    }

    return lista;
}

   //este metodo se parece al prepareEdit me redirecciona a la vista 
public String VisualizarComiteInformacion(Long id){
    current = ejbFacade.findByIdProceso(id);
    System.out.println("***************************************************");
    System.out.println("El resultado de contestar demanda es: " + current);

    Map<String, Object> sessionMap = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap();
    sessionMap.put("comite",current);

    return "ViewInformacionComite";
}
   //este metodo se parece al prepareEdit me redirecciona a la vista
public String PrepareEditComiteInformacion(Long id){
    current = ejbFacade.findByIdProceso(id);
    System.out.println("***************************************************");
    System.out.println("El resultado de contestar demanda es: " + current);

    Map<String, Object> sessionMap = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap();
    sessionMap.put("comite",current);

    return "EditInformacionComite";
}

//actualiza el registro 
public String actualizar(OajComiteProceso comiteProceso){
    ejbFacade.editarCoomiteProceso(comiteProceso);
    return  "ListInformacionComite";
}


public String prepareListInformacionComite() {
    recreateModel();
    return "ListInformacionComite";
}
```

}

la vista es la siguiente:

```
<ui:composition template="/template.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="title">
        <h:outputText value="#{bundle.EditOajComiteProcesoTitle}"></h:outputText>
    </ui:define>
    <ui:define name="body">
        <h:panelGroup id="messagePanel" layout="block">
            <h:messages errorStyle="color: red" infoStyle="color: green" layout="table"/>
        </h:panelGroup>
        <h:form>
            <h:panelGrid columns="4">
               <h:outputLabel value="Proceso" for="proceso" />
               <h:selectOneMenu id="oajProceso" value="#{oajComiteProcesoController.selected.oajProceso}" title="#{bundle.EditOajComiteProcesoTitle_oajProceso}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{bundle.EditOajComiteProcesoRequiredMessage_oajProceso}">
                <f:selectItems value="#{oajComiteProcesoController.listadoComiteProcesosJudiciales()}" var="com" itemLabel="#{com.oajProceso.numeroProceso}" itemValue="#{com.oajProceso.idProceso}"/>
                <f:ajax execute="#{oajComiteProcesoController.createInformacionComite(com.oajProceso.idProceso)}" immediate="true"/>
            </h:selectOneMenu>

            </h:panelGrid>
            <h:commandLink action="#{oajComiteProcesoController.createInformacionComite(oajComiteProcesoController.selected.oajProceso.idProceso)}" value="#{bundle.EditOajComiteProcesoSaveLink}"/>
            <br />
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

El Formulario muestra de forma correcta la informacion

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y en el html se ve así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo cual es correcto, porque me esta mostrando el número del proceso y el id que en este caso es 2.

También he visto que se puede hacer un converter personalizado pero no se como realizarlo, ya que no entiendo muy bien su funcionamiento, agradezco su colaboración

Comment: ¿Te refieres a cuando se ejecuta el ajax? ¿O cuando se envía el form? ¿Te sale algún mensaje en el log?

Comment: Sjuan76 en ambos casos me envía un valor nulo, y no se porque, gracias por tu respuesta y agradezco si me puedes ayudar.

Comment: Para poder darte una solución necesitamos ver el código de la case OajComiteProcesoController y OajComiteProceso y la vista xhtml, o un ejemplo simple que replique tu problema de lo contrario lo que digamos son solo ideas no soluciones, como lo indica dice SJuan76 "Sobre la parte del envío del form, no tengo información suficiente. En todo caso no muestras información de log ni la definición de los beans/propiedades, así que es posible que haya otros fallos".

Comment: Roberto E Moran @Ro

Comment: @RobertoEMoran edite el post y agregue el controller OajComiteProcesoController, el pojo OajComiteProceso  y la vista, ademas agregue los captures de la vista y su codigo html

Comment: ¿Cuál es el scope de tu bean `OajComiteProcesoController`?

Comment: @Garrizano ViewScoped

Comment: Cuando es ViewScoped al hacer un cambio de vista (página) se pierden los valores de los elementos.

Answer (score -1):

Por la parte de Ajax, una cuestión es que *execute* [no hace lo que piensas](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/ajax.html):

> Evaluates to Collection. This is a space separated list of client ids of components that will participate in the "execute" portion of the Request Processing Lifecycle. If a literal is specified the ids must be space delimited. Any of the keywords "@this", "@form", "@all", "@none" may be specified in the id list. If not specified, the default value of "@this" is assumed. For example, @this clientIdOne clientIdTwo.

Básicamente *execute* indica qué componentes se enviarán al servidor para procesar el Ajax. Con tu código, se ejecuta *oajComiteProcesoController.createInformacionComite*, pero **solo para evaluar la expresión y sacar la lista de componentes**, en ese momento en tu modelo *com.oajProceso.idProceso* sigue teniendo el valor original.

Deberías usar el atributo *listener* para especificar el método a ejecutar; puedes obtener el valor del *idProceso* inyectando una referencia al proceso *oajProceso* en tu controlador o quizás mediante el método *getComponent* del evento que se pasa al controlador.

Sobre la parte del envío del form, no tengo información suficiente. En todo caso no muestras información de log ni la definición de los beans/propiedades, así que es posible que haya otros fallos (por ejemplo, que no haya *converter* para convertir el valor recibido en la instancia del tipo que espera el *setter*).

Comment: edite el post y agregue el controller OajComiteProcesoController, el pojo OajComiteProceso y la vista, ademas agregue los captures de la vista y su codigo html, espero con esa información sea mas claro y me puedas ayudar.